# Is my Turkey e-Visa valid if I have used my single-entry Schengen visa?

Tags: schengen-visas, turkey, e-visas

I have a single entry Schengen visa (business) valid from 16 Nov - 30 Nov 2018. I am planning to visit Belgium on 16 November and Slovakia on 18 November. Then I plan to visit Turkey on 24-26 November.

I have already obtained a Turkey e-Visa valid from 17 November 2018 to 15 May 2019. Is it possible for me to travel to Turkey with this single-entry e-Visa since I am going to use my single-entry Schengan visa before travel to Turkey?

Comment: Yes it is valid for entry until the date your Schengen Visa expires. Even if you have used the single entry already.

Answer (score -3):

As Turkey is not a member of EU, you can visit Turkey until the expire date of your visa, even if you go through Schengen countries.

Comment: Welcome to the site, Ismail. My edit was just to fix the spelling on a few words.

Comment: The asker doesn't think Turkey is in the EU. The point is that having a Schengen visa allows you to get a Turkish e-visa, and the asker is wondering if their Turkish e-visa is still valid after they've used their single-entry Schengen visa.

Comment: @DavidRicherby My answer is correct. As OP has a single entry schengen visa. He thinks using first the schengen visa can affect his turkish visa. As Turkey is not  a member of UE it can not affect Turkish visa. He can still come in Turkey